# SublimeText + FTPSync : new lines on upload

Tags: ftp, sublimetext2

(I do not know if this is the right place)

After save/auto-upload with FTPSync package, distant file has new lines every line. So line number doesn't match and local/distant files doesn't match to. How can I fix it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: This file has UNIX encoding ?

Comment: Try to switch to UNIX encoding. EDIT > Convert carriage return.

Comment: local: Windows, distant: Macintosh. AINSI both

Comment: I can't encode every files after save...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In `Preferences > Settings - Default`

Look for: `"default_line_ending"`

Tweak that setting and save and re-upload your file.

If your line endings are windows (CRLF) it can be interpreted as two line breaks instead of one in unix based systems (that use LF alone as line ending).

Some FTP programs automatically convert line endings to avoid this. You can also look into your ftp plugin options to see if there is a way to weak it there and leave your editor's settings alone.

If you are using a project workflow, you can also modify line endings for the project and leave the global option as you have it now. Check out step 5 on [this tut](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sublime-text-2-project-bliss--net-27256) for more details on manipulating settings for a specific project while leaving your global settings unchanged for other files opened outside that project.

This can also happen if there is more than one person touching the file. For example, if you modify it, save it and re-upload it, then someone else does the same, and you open it again, you would see the extra line breaks if the other person uses a different system or editor.

Comment: I switch to SFTP plugin. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I too use it. Never had an issue with it.